# Por que usar nodeJs com funções assíncronas com AWS-Lambda?

Tags: node.js, expressões-lambda, amazon-aws

Os serviços de AWS-Lambda podem ser desenvolvido em Java, C#, Python, Go, PowerShell e finalmente NodeJS ([DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-app.html)).

Atualmente se usa o NodeJs como backend de aplicações com a vantagem de se desenvolver nativamente requisições assíncronas ao servidor através de assync-wait ou promises. Isso traz uma camada de complexidade ao código muito maior do que quando comparado com a mesma aplicação que não faz uso de funções assíncronas.

A idéia é simples - se vc tem um servidor rodando em NodeJs que vai fornecer uma função (sendEmail por exemplo) e ele pode responder a 4 requisições simultâneas no mesmo pool de treads - ou ao mesmo tempo.

Uma das vantagens da AWS-Lambda é que a função (ela mesma) é auto escalável e permite concorrências naturalmente (Independentemente da língua escolhida - [DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html)).

Ora, se naturalmente a função lambda te oferece a possibilidade de ter [1000 instâncias disponíveis em  qualquer momento](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html), qual seria a vantagem de usar NodeJs com a justificativa de se ter a mesma função (sendEmail) assíncrona?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu não sou especialista NodeJS e não uso ele com lambdas, mas até onde compreendo: a utilização de promises com lambda (https://medium.com/vandium-software/simplify-and-secure-your-node-js-aws-lambda-code-with-vandium-part-2-30c404884e21) simplifica códigos de network requests sucessivos (cascateados), facilitando a manutenção e eliminando os callbacks.

No ES2017 temos o async/await que simplifica ainda mais a utilização de promises (https://irvinlim.com/blog/async-await-on-aws-lambda/) deixando ainda mais fácil de ler e dar manutenção.

Em resumo, até onde eu compreendo: o objetivo de usar promises ou async/await com lambda não é aumentar o pool da function construída (isto realmente não faz sentido para mim também) e sim simplificar a construção de uma function que necessita chamar outras 3, por exemplo, de forma cascateada.

Também não me parece uma complexidade a mais utilizar, na verdade o objetivo é justamente remover a complexidade de usar callbacks, talvez esteja mais relacionado ao aprendizado da nova syntax e utilização no dia-a-dia.

Veja o que achas dos links que coloquei acima e se faz sentido meu comentário. Abrs =)